# Yii session have prefix

Tags: yii

**I am maintaining a Yii application, when i am printing Yii session it looks like this:**

Array
(
    [cb35f057aa124d26e8793014875ce939_*id] => 1
    [cb35f057aa124d26e8793014875ce939*_name] => admin
    [cb35f057aa124d26e8793014875ce939__states] => Array()
    [cb35f057aa124d26e8793014875ce939email] => webmaster@example.com
    [cb35f057aa124d26e8793014875ce939username] => admin
    [cb35f057aa124d26e8793014875ce939create_at] => 2013-01-14 07:44:22
    [cb35f057aa124d26e8793014875ce939lastvisit_at] => 2013-09-13 06:09:17
    [cb35f057aa124d26e8793014875ce939state_id] => 1
)

i don't know where to find this number cb35f057aa124d26e8793014875ce939 so that i can use session data in my method. it is looks like fixed. does anybody know what is it ?

Comment: Use yii [session class to manage session data](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession)

Answer (score 0):

You should use session variables via Yii API which is

```
Yii::app()->session['var'] = 'something'; //setting a value
echo Yii::app()->session['var']; //reading a value
```

Comment: i know that, but my query is how to use existing keys because they have some strange prefix.

Answer (score 0):

this is not session ID, this is application specific prefix which can be found by getStateKeyPrefix()

Answer (score 0):

The above numbers are probably set by calling `setStateKeyPrefix()` function somewhere in the code.

Here is explanation of the function:

**setStateKeyPrefix()** - *Sets a prefix for the name of the session variables storing user session data.*

Additionally, you can use `getStateKeyPrefix()` function to see weather or not prefix is set.

Answer (score -1):

The prefix is the php session id  and u can get it by

```
Yii::app()->session->getSessionID();
```